# How to add IMG SRC attribute into SPAN CSS background-image on click

Tags: html, jquery, css, image, lightbox

How can I add #largeImage1 SRC attribute into the span background-image everytime #thumbs1 is clicked? It should update span background-image with the new SRC.

I can't seem to get it work. My syntaxes are not working. Can you please help?

```
 <a href="#img1">
  <img id="largeImage1" src="google-1.png" />
 </a>
 
 <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="img1">
  <span></span>
 </a>

  <div id="thumbs1">
    <img src="google-1.png" />
    <img src="google-2.png" />
    <img src="google-3.png" />
    <img src="google-4.png" />
  </div>


$('#thumbs1').delegate('img', 'click', function() { <-- This is working fine
    $('#largeImage1').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large')); <-- This is working fine
    $('span').css('background-image', 'url()'); <---- This is the problem, I can see in the inspection tool, that when clicked it adds background-image to span but doesn't add image SRC inside it. I don't know what to call inside the url. I checked online but seemed confusing
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I do not see the text `"thumb"` in the SRC of any of the images. Also wich URL should be in the `url()` section?

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to add 'largeImage1' SRC in 'span' 'background-image'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fully clear from your example what you want to do. Here is an example that might help you.

```js
$(function() {
  function moveShade(target) {
    $("#thumbs1 .shade").css({
      width: $(target).width(),
      height: $(target).height(),
      top: $(target).position().top,
      left: $(target).position().left
    });
  }
  $('#thumbs1').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
    $('#largeImage1').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    $('.lightbox span').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')');
    $("#thumbs1 .active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    moveShade(".active");
  });
  moveShade(".active");
});
```

```css
a[href='#img1'] img {
  width: 480px;
}

#thumbs1 {
  position: relative;
}

#thumbs1 img {
  width: 100px;
}

#thumbs1 .shade {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#img1">
  <img id="largeImage1" src="https://i.imgur.com/HGKqg1T.jpeg" />
</a>

<a href="#" class="lightbox" id="img1">
  <span></span>
</a>

<div id="thumbs1">
  <img class="active" src="https://i.imgur.com/HGKqg1T.jpeg" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bLvEb3m.jpeg" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IjT9NLy.jpeg" />
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CkIsdeq.jpeg" />
  <div class="shade"></div>
</div>
```

You can see, in the CSS, you update the `url()` but you must add in the URL string that you want. This, I assume, will come from one of the other thumbnails.

Comment: Thank you very much mate, this is exactly I wanted. Sorry for the confusion mate. It's now working as intended mate. Thank you very much and really appreciate it mate :)